# How can I invalidate cache only on specific RTK query calls?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I have an infinite scroll RTK query app that makes endpoint queries and merges the data on each call so the results get concatenated on scroll down. However, on specific calls to this same endpoint, I'd like to invalidate the cache and start over. Here is my query:

```
getArticles: builder.query({
  query: (args) => {
      let { page, filter } = args;
      let filtersString = filter.join(',');
      return {
          url: '/apiPath?offset=${page*5}&limit=1000&categories=${filtersString}''
      }
  },

  serializeQueryArgs: ({ endpointName }) => {
      return endpointName;
  },

  merge: (currentCache, newItems) => {
      currentCache.push(...newItems)
  },

 forceRefetch({ currentArg, previousArg }) {
      return currentArg !== previousArg;
  }

})
```

Ideally, I'd like to use the same query because I want the data to refetch whenever `page` `limit` or `categories` change -- but occasionally, I'd like to force a total refresh. Is this possible?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

I solve this by removing all the cache.

> dispatch(api.util.resetApiState())

I know it's now a good approach we have to remove the cache only for this end point. I also try provided tag but no luck. invalidateTags works fine its recall the api but due to cache its merge the data because we are using merge.

Answer (score -1):

```
  merge: (currentData, newData, { arg }) => {

    if (arg?.refech && arg.page == 1)
        return newData;
    else
        return {
            ...newData,
            data: [...currentData?.data, ...newData?.data]
        }
},
```